# Twitter Search API returns zero results when ORing search term

Tags: search, twitter

Although previously (within 6 months) we were seeing the OR operator within the twitter search api work correctly, we are now seeing that if one of the ORed terms returns zero results it appears to be treated like an AND - so nothing is returned.

Here's an example using the web search (which appears to work the same way):

Search term A: "@TheIHI" -> many results
https://twitter.com/search?q=%40TheIHI

Search term B: "#IHI26Forum" -> zero results
https://twitter.com/search?q=%23IHI26Forum

Search A OR B: "@TheIHI OR #IHI26Forum" -> zero results
https://twitter.com/search?q=%40TheIHI%20OR%20%23IHI26Forum

Any suggestions on how to address this?  Or anyone else encounter a similar issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get around this by excluding `@` and `#`.

For example - https://twitter.com/search?q=TheIHI%20OR%20IHI26Forum

So, just searching for "TheIHI OR IHI26Forum".

That seems to work - but I don't know why!

Comment: Also, the capitalization of the letters "I" in the hashtag appeared to be affecting the number of search results - but just for the hashtag I was using (not for others).  Very weird.